# How to sum up hierarchy Data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have two table

Table 1:Master 
Table 2: Slave

```
Master Table Definition                       Slave Table Definition
mID--label-----ParentID                          ID-----Label----mID----Amount
1---A----------Null                               1------X--------1------20
2---B-----------1                                 2------Y--------1------30
3---C-----------1                                 3------Z--------2------20
4---D-----------2                                 4------X1-------4------50
5---E-----------4                                 5------X2-------5------100

Relation From Master table                     Relation from slave table
A=B+C                                          A=X+Y
B=D                                            B=Z
D=E                                            D=X1
                                               E=X2
```

Now,
How to sum up the tree of a master with slave table
    A=(E+D+B)+C
    therefore, A=sum of the value of(X2+X1+Z)
    B=(D+E)
    therefore, B=X1+X2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Master Table Definition

mID--label-----ParentID
1---A----------Null
2---B-----------1
3---C-----------1
4---D-----------2
5---E-----------4

i create another table to keep relation

id-----childID----parentID
1--------2-----------1
2--------3-----------1
3--------4-----------2
4--------4-----------1
5--------5-----------4
6--------5-----------2
7--------5-----------1

in this way i solved...........
```